# @WebAppConfiguration and @ContextConfiguration for Spring Boot + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, thymeleaf

Given a Spring Boot + Thymeleaf web application (this is nearly identical to the Spring project's [gs-consuming-rest "initial" code tree](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-securing-web/tree/master/initial)):

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── hello
    │   │       ├── Application.java
    │   │       ├── Config.java
    │   │       └── Controller.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── templates
    │           └── index.html
    └── test
        └── java
            └── hello
                └── ControllerTest.java
```

...the user is greeted just fine with "Hello World!" at `http://localhost:8080/`, but the wiring of Spring's "context" does not seem to apply within the integration test (`ControllerTest.java`):

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

What is wrong with the **project layout**, and/or the **configuration annotations** in the test?

*`src/main/webapp/` is intentionally missing, along with things like `web.xml` and `WEB-INF/`.  The goal here is to use minimal configuration, with an integration test to test-drive the development of the view and controller of the application.*

Gory details below.  Sorry in advance for the "wall of text."

---

#### pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### Application.java

```java
package hello;

// ...

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

#### Controller.java

```java
package hello;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {
}
```

#### Config.java

```java
package hello;

// ...

@Configuration
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
  }
}
```

#### ControllerTest.java

```java
package hello;

// ...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
public class ControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc
        .perform(get("/"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@ContextConfiguration` but `@ SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead and point it to your application class instead of the configuration class.

Comment: @M.Deinum I use @ SpringApplicationConfiguration. How can I use a different @ Configuration class for tests?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @M.Deinum for helping me to realize that:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
public class ControllerTest {
```

...should be:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class ControllerTest {
```

---

I suppose that `@ContextConfiguration` is meant for integration tests in **Spring**, whereas `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is meant for integration tests in **Spring Boot**.

According to the [Javadoc for the latter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html):

> Class-level annotation that is used to determine how to load and configure an ApplicationContext for integration tests.
>
> Similar to the standard @ContextConfiguration but uses Spring Boot's SpringApplicationContextLoader.

Comment: @SpringApplicationConfiguration is deprecated in favor of other things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417530/what-is-the-proper-annotation-since-springapplicationconfiguration-webintegra

Comment: I am facing same issue but i am using @SpringBootTest instead... Any idea how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

If you use boot, you an use @SpringBootTest  or one of Test Slices (@WebMvcTest in your case) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.test-auto-configuration.slices

If you use spring core, you can use @WebappConfiguration + @ContextConfiguration

Answer (score -1):

```
    package com.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import netgloo.Application;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class SmokeTest {


    @Test
    public void contexLoads() throws Exception {
     System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: This loads entire context of application to be used in TestClass