# What is the proper annotation since @SpringApplicationConfiguration, @WebIntegration, is deprecated in Spring Boot Framework?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-annotations

What is the proper annotation since `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and `@WebIntegration` are deprecated as of Spring Boot Framework 1.4?  I'm trying to play around with unit testing.

Comment: @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.MOCK)

Comment: Take a look at https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

Comment: It is not an answer to you question but, Spring boot is not a framework. But it is an opinionated view of Spring Framework. https://springhow.com/spring-boot-and-spring/

Answer (score 53):

Take a look into JavaDocs of deprecated classes:

```
* @deprecated as of 1.4 in favor of
 * {@link org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest} with
 * {@code webEnvironment=RANDOM_PORT} or {@code webEnvironment=DEFINED_PORT}.
 */
...
@Deprecated
public @interface WebIntegrationTest {
```

---

```
* @deprecated as of 1.4 in favor of {@link SpringBootTest} or direct use of
* {@link SpringBootContextLoader}.
*/
...
@Deprecated
public @interface SpringApplicationConfiguration {
```

> Is there also a replacement for TestRestTemplate()?

Yes, here it is:

```
 * @deprecated as of 1.4 in favor of
 * {@link org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate}
 */
@Deprecated
public class TestRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {
```

Answer (score 30):

A good place to start is now probably:
[Testing improvements in Spring Boot 1.4](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4).

They describe a basic sample like the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyTest {
}
```

as a replacement to, one of many:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(MyApp.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class MyTest {
}
```

Comment: how does the upper version of you know that the ApplicationConfiguration is in the class MyApp.class ? when I implement it your way it fails to load the applicationContext

Comment: Good question, I do not know but it might be only one runing App at a time.

Answer (score 9):

you can use @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication.

for testing purpose you can use 
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment='your value') or simply @SpringBootTest

please refer :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

for testing the REST, you can use @RestClientTest and configure a RestTemplateBuilder.

Answer (score 6):

You should use this annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = main_class)
```

Comment: This doesn't work as during integration test my app is unable to get the database URL params from the properties file.

Comment: @NeerajJain to be able to get them just a small tweak is necessary:  @ContextConfiguration(classes = main_class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the following with no problem at all:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
```

Whereas **Application** is the name of my main class.