# SpringBootTest Integration Tests Fail (403 Forbidden) after upgrade from 1.3.2 to 1.5.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, integration-testing, spring-cloud

I am in the process of upgrading several apps from SpringBoot 1.3.2.RELEASE to 1.5.3, using springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.RELEASE'

As a part of this upgrade process, the annotations in my existing integration tests changed:

Old, [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417530/what-is-the-proper-annotation-since-springapplicationconfiguration-webintegra) way:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Unroll
@WebAppConfiguration
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TokenServerApplication)
```

New, upgraded way:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = TokenServerApplication)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Unroll
```

This seems to compile just fine, but I noticed a variety of my tests began breaking, giving a 403 Forbidden response.

These tests that are failing should require sending a request with a valid 'x-auth-token' header. The response from my service should give a 403 "Not authenticated", but the message I am getting does not contain the "Not authenticated" message (it is more generic), and further, tests that should pass with valid tokens are also getting 403'd.

I am using the following to construct my requests:

```
@Autowired TestRestTemplate restTemplate
```

And the tests are all roughly set up the same:

```
  @Test
  void "test valid token"() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers.set("x-auth-token", tokenIngestExternal)
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers)
    ResponseEntity<Map> result = restTemplate.exchange("/authenticate", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class)
    assertTrue(result.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK)
    Map map = result.getBody()
    assertTrue map.get('iss').equals("A")
    assertTrue map.get('sub').equals("B")
    assertTrue map.get('aud').equals("C")
    assertTrue map.get('roles').equals("D")
  }
```

This same basic methodology worked just fine before the upgrade to 1.5.3 and using the latest annotations for the integration test.

Am I missing an annotation or parameter or something? What's the dealio?